# How to ignore submodules per Scala version, say 2.10?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-module SBT build cross-building against Scala 2.10, 2.11 and 2.12. I would like to add a submodule for Java 8 support. However, this is only possible for Scala 2.11 (and 2.12). My goal is to have SBT build this specific submodule only for 2.11 and 2.12 and ignore it for 2.10; in particular, not publish an artifact for 2.10.

My current working hypothesis is to override the `publish`, `libraryDependencies` and `unmanagedSourceDirectories` keys based on the Scala version, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Alexey Romanov has pointed out that https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28404706/revisions is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@simon_yann](http://twitter.com/simon_yann/status/642238307968110592) on Twitter wrote, I wrote [sbt-doge](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-doge) for this reason.

> sbt-doge is a sbt plugin to aggregate across `crossScalaVersions` for multi-project builds, which I call partial cross building.

Try

```
> ;so clean; such test; very publishLocal
```